# Problem in displaying float value in label from Database:

Tags: asp.net, floating-point

I have stored 1000.5 value (datatype float)  in database.. but when i am retrieving that value and displaying in label. so it displays like 1000.04998779297..

what should i do?

thnx

Answer (score 0):

You need to format the value ...

```
String.Format("{0:0.0}", 123.43543545);
```

Result:

> 123.4

---

Check [String Format for Double [C#]](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-double/)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do using

```
Convert.ToDouble(dt.rows[0][0]).ToString("0.00");
```